# Scatter plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to do a scatter (xy) plot of variables in a melted data frame as shown below.

```
df
class var  mean        
0      x   4.25 
0      y   6.25 
1      x   2.00 
1      y  11.00
```

I have tried this, but it plots 4 points. How can plot x and y?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=mean, y=mean, group=var, colour=class)) +
geom_point( size=5, shape=21, fill="white")
```

Comment: This rare, but your data is in a format that's 'too' long. You need x and y-values on the same row for each observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Heroka pointed out, you need the data to be in a more wide type format. If the data was read in like this, you may use the following to convert it.

```
## you don't need this since you already have df
text = "class var mean
0 x 4.25
0 y 6.25
1 x 2.00
1 y 11.00"
df = read.delim(textConnection(text),header=TRUE,strip.white=TRUE,     
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = " ");df2

## use this library to switch from long-wide
library(reshape2)

df2 = dcast(df, class ~ var, value.var = "mean")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=class)) +
  geom_point( size=5, shape=21, fill="white")
```

[image]

Comment: And I would convert class to factor; the current scale is unnecessary/confusing.